# How to show a detail page of a product with Laravel and Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I created a Laravel Jetstream lifewire page from a tutorial.
I show a list of records, and added a details button.

```
<button wire:click="showdetails({{ $vehicle->id }})"class="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-1.5 border border-transparent text-xs font-medium rounded shadow-sm text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700">
   Details
</button>
```

When I click onto this button, I want to see the detail page of the record (new view, not the view of the list).

Info vehicle.php I added this function

```
public function showdetails($id)
{
    $this->vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
    return view('livewire.vehicle.details');
}
```

I made something wrong, because this view will not be shown.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a route to your Livewire `ShowVehicle` component:

`Route::get('/vehicle/{id}', ShowVehicle::class);`

2. Redirect to that route:

   ```
   public function showdetails($id)
   {
       return redirect()->to("/vehicle/$id");
   }
   ```
3. Display item details with ShowVehicle component:

   ```
   class ShowVehicle extends Component
   {
      public $vehicle;

      public function mount($id)
      {
         $this->vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
      }

      public function render()
      {
         return view('livewire.vehicle.details', [
            'vehicle' => $this->vehicle,
         ]);
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: I would suggest two things: 1. use named routes. 2. You can probably omit the entire `showDetails()` method and just put a link to that route, that means that you don't need to request the server to get a redirect.